Is it possible to exclude a pid from perf record (but capture all others)?
I want to run the perf record, but filter out a few pids. Reading the perf record doc I am little confused as to how to mention the pid filter. This does not seems to work:
perf record  -e cycles --filter 'pid != 514900'

This CPU does not support address filtering

 Usage: perf record [<options>] [<command>]
    or: perf record [<options>] -- <command> [<options>]

        --filter <filter>
                          event filter


I am using a wrong syntax?

In your question title, I think you mean "exclude" rather than "execute", based on the question body.  Re-edit if you meant something else.

The man page says --exclude-perf adds common_pid != $PERFPID to filters, so yes apparently something like this should be possible, apparently with common_pid.
